# how to draw these arrows?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I know my question is not  a good question. I just want to know if this type of diagram is suitable to use tikz to draw.

I want to use this picture in my class, but the picture is not a vector picture, I want to draw it by myself, but I was stuck in drawing these arrows.

[image]

see: Stanislas Dehaene: Varieties of numerical abilities. Cognition, 44 (1992) 1-42

Comment: This seems to be a do-it-for-me-question. Please show what you've got so far (code example, MWE). Also please specify which arrows you are interested in (there are two different types).

Comment: Possible with TikZ, but i would use *Inkscape* to draw this. It exports vector graphics. And if really needed, you can export to TikZ as well.

Comment: @Johannes_B You know my meaning! Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @Texnician I want to know how to draw  two types of arrow. I search the pgfmanual's arrow part. I have not found any useful information to draw them. So I just want to know if there are any methods.

Comment: What about [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84148/124577)?

Comment: very good! This can help me draw one type of arrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way of drawing those arrows, using a `pic`. It's not perfect I think, but it might do the trick.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows,calc,fit}
\tikzset{
dashedarrow/.pic={
  \node [transform shape,single arrow,draw,single arrow tip angle=50] (x) {\phantom{abc}};
  \draw ($(x.after tail)+(-2pt,0)$) rectangle ($(x.before tail)+(-12pt,0)$);
  \draw ($(x.after tail)+(-14pt,0)$) rectangle ($(x.before tail)+(-21pt,0)$);
  \draw ($(x.after tail)+(-23pt,0)$) rectangle ($(x.before tail)+(-27pt,0)$);
  \draw ($(x.after tail)+(-29pt,0)$) rectangle ($(x.before tail)+(-31pt,0)$) coordinate (ll);
  \node [transform shape,fit=(ll)(x.before tip)(x.after tip)(x.tip),inner sep=0pt] (-border) {};
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \pic [blue] {dashedarrow};

 \pic (a) at (0,2) {dashedarrow};
 \node [above] at (a-border.north) {Stuff};

 \pic [rotate=160] (b) at (2,0) {dashedarrow};
 \path (b-border.south west) -- node[sloped,above] {Other stuff} (b-border.south east);

 \pic [rotate=30,scale=0.5] (c) at (2,2) {dashedarrow};
 \path (c-border.north west) -- node[sloped,above] {Foo} (c-border.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: very good! I learned from your example that it is very complicated drawing my picture . Thanks!