# tiki fancy arrow in tikz environment

Tags: tikz-arrows

I came across this page where they explain how to draw fancy arrows with shadows etc.

[Fancy arrows with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84143/fancy-arrows-with-tikz)

However, in the example, the arrows are embedded in the text. I would like to draw it in the tikzfigure environment between nodes.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[](a){};
 \node[right of=a,node distance=10cm](b){};

 \draw[ ??](a) -- (b);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

What is the correct syntax in the example?

Comment: arrows in the answers in your link are nodes and they can not be simple draw as lines.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your comment. I would like to know how to draw an arrow between two nodes with the given style in the link.

Comment: arrows (for example from arrows.meta) as lines yes, as nodes no (only if node fit this two coordinates, however, in this you limited quite limited

Comment: Could you post a MWE so we can see what you want to achieve precisely ?

Comment: I cannot, because I don't have a working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the code from the accepted answer to [Fancy arrows with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84143/fancy-arrows-with-tikz/84148#84148), then note that the `arrowstyle` style takes an argument that determines the length of the arrow. Hence, if you have

```
\node [draw] (a) {A};
\node [draw,right=5cm of a] (b) {B};
```

so you know the distance between the nodes is 5cm, then you can use

```
\node [arrowstyle=5cm,right=0pt of a] {};
```

to get such an arrow starting at `a`, ending at `b`.

---

Addendum: The `right of=` syntax you used is considered deprecated, instead you should load the `positioning` library and use `right=of`, as I did above. See [Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386)

---

If you don't know the exact distance, or you need to rotate it (i.e. if node `b` isn't straight right of `a`), then you can load the `calc` library and calculate distance and angle like this:

```
\path
 let
   \p1=(a2.south east), % start point
   \p2=(b2.north west), % end point
   \n1={veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)}, % distance between start and end
   \n2={atan2(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)}   % angle between start and end
 in
  node [arrowstyle=\n1,
        right=0 of a2.south east,
        rotate=\n2,
        fading angle=\n2 % only  affects shadow
       ] {};
```

Note that the colour fading itself is not rotated, so that always goes from top to bottom. Note also that because this is a node, not a normal line path, you can only have straight lines, curved or kinked arrows are not possible.

[image]

```
\documentclass[svgnames,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  fadings,
  shapes.arrows,
  shadows,
  positioning
}   

\tikzfading[name=arrowfading, top color=transparent!0, bottom color=transparent!95]

\tikzset{
  arrowfill/.style={
     top color=OrangeRed!20,
     bottom color=Red,
     general shadow={fill=black, shadow yshift=-0.8ex, path fading=arrowfading}
  },
  arrowstyle/.style={
     draw=FireBrick,
     arrowfill,
     single arrow,
     minimum height=#1,
     single arrow head extend=.4cm
   }
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node [draw] (a) {A};
 \node [draw,right=5cm of a] (b) {B};
 \node [arrowstyle=5cm,right=0pt of a]{};


 \node [draw,below=1cm of a] (a2) {A2};
 \node [draw,below right=3cm of a2] (b2) {B2};
 \node [arrowstyle=3cm,
        right=0 of a2.south east,
        rotate=-45,
        fading angle=-45 % only  affects shadow
       ] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```