# Draw arrow between Venn diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

Below is the code:

```
\documentclass[svgnames,border=5mm]{beamer}

\hypersetup{colorlinks}
\definecolor{bleudefrance}{rgb}{0.19, 0.55, 0.91}
\definecolor{aquamarine}{rgb}{0.5, 1.0, 0.83}
\definecolor{electricyellow}{rgb}{1.0, 1.0, 0.0}
\definecolor{robineggblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.8, 0.8}
\definecolor{ballblue}{rgb}{0.13, 0.67, 0.8}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Vers une modélisation du milieu complexe}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{12cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
\uncover<1->{
  \begin{scope}[blend group = soft light]
  \fill[gray!20!white]   (2.5,3) circle (30pt and 15pt);
    \fill[red!30!white]   ( 90:1.2) circle (2);
    \fill[green!30!white] (210:1.2) circle (2);
    \fill[cyan!30!white]  (330:1.2) circle (2);
    \fill[pink!30!white]   (90:-3.2) circle (2);
  \end{scope}
  \node at (2.5,3)    {Contexte};
  \node at ( 90:2)    {Pluridisciplinarité};
  \node at (-1.5,-0.97)   {Climat};
  \node at ( 330:2)   {\bfseries{\underline{Sol}}};
  \node at ( 90:-3.2)  { \Large Blablabla};
  \node [font=\Large] {Vous};
}
\uncover<2->{
\begin{scope}[xshift=7cm]
  \begin{scope}[blend group = soft light]
  \fill[gray!30!white]   (2.5,3) circle (30pt and 15pt);
    \fill[robineggblue!40!white]   ( 90:1.2) circle (2);
    \fill[bleudefrance!40!white] (210:1.2) circle (2);
    \fill[aquamarine!40!white]  (330:1.2) circle (2);
    \fill[ballblue!40!white]  (90:-3.2) circle (2);
  \end{scope}
  \node at (2.5,3)    {Objectif};
  \node at ( 90:2)    {Caractérisation};
  \node at (-2,-0.98)   {Imagerie};
  \node at (1.5,-0.98)   {Micromécanique};
  \node at ( 90:-3.2)  {Modélisation};
  \node at ( 0,-3.6)  {numérique};
  \node at (0,0) [font=\huge,
      color = black,
      align = center
   ]{
      \bfseries{Sol}
   };
\end{scope}
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\hspace{1cm}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

which produces two slides

[image]

[image]

I want to draw an arrow from the nod of the "Sol" in the left Venn diagram pointing towards the word "Sol" to the right one.

[image]

The arrows should be as the arrows of this thread

[tiki fancy arrow in tikz environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/428642/tiki-fancy-arrow-in-tikz-environment)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just give the nodes some names, and draw an arrow between them.

```
\documentclass[svgnames,border=5mm]{beamer}

\hypersetup{colorlinks}
\definecolor{bleudefrance}{rgb}{0.19, 0.55, 0.91}
\definecolor{aquamarine}{rgb}{0.5, 1.0, 0.83}
\definecolor{electricyellow}{rgb}{1.0, 1.0, 0.0}
\definecolor{robineggblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.8, 0.8}
\definecolor{ballblue}{rgb}{0.13, 0.67, 0.8}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{
  fadings,
  shapes.arrows,
  shadows,
  positioning
}   

\tikzfading[name=arrowfading, top color=transparent!0, bottom color=transparent!95]

\tikzset{
  arrowfill/.style={
     top color=OrangeRed!20,
     bottom color=Red,
     general shadow={fill=black, shadow yshift=-0.8ex, path fading=arrowfading}
  },
  arrowstyle/.style={
     draw=FireBrick,
     arrowfill,
     single arrow,
     minimum height=#1,
     single arrow head extend=.2cm
   }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Vers une modélisation du milieu complexe}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{12cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
\uncover<1->{
  \begin{scope}[blend group = soft light]
  \fill[gray!20!white]   (2.5,3) circle (30pt and 15pt);
    \fill[red!30!white]   ( 90:1.2) circle (2);
    \fill[green!30!white] (210:1.2) circle (2);
    \fill[cyan!30!white]  (330:1.2) circle (2);
    \fill[pink!30!white]   (90:-3.2) circle (2);
  \end{scope}
  \node at (2.5,3)    {Contexte};
  \node at ( 90:2)    {Pluridisciplinarité};
  \node at (-1.5,-0.97)   {Climat};
  \node at ( 330:2) (SOL1)   {\bfseries{\underline{Sol}}};
  \node at ( 90:-3.2)  { \Large Blablabla};
  \node [font=\Large] {Vous};
}
\uncover<2->{
\begin{scope}[xshift=7cm]
  \begin{scope}[blend group = soft light]
  \fill[gray!30!white]   (2.5,3) circle (30pt and 15pt);
    \fill[robineggblue!40!white]   ( 90:1.2) circle (2);
    \fill[bleudefrance!40!white] (210:1.2) circle (2);
    \fill[aquamarine!40!white]  (330:1.2) circle (2);
    \fill[ballblue!40!white]  (90:-3.2) circle (2);
  \end{scope}
  \node at (2.5,3)    {Objectif};
  \node at ( 90:2)    {Caractérisation};
  \node at (-2,-0.98)   {Imagerie};
  \node at (1.5,-0.98)   {Micromécanique};
  \node at ( 90:-3.2)  {Modélisation};
  \node at ( 0,-3.6)  {numérique};
  \node at (0,0) [font=\huge,
      color = black,
      align = center
   ] (SOL2) {
      \bfseries{Sol}
   };
\end{scope}
%\draw (SOL1)--(SOL2);
\node [arrowstyle=3.5cm,
        right=0 of SOL1.east,
        rotate=12,
        fading angle=12 % only  affects shadow
       ] {};
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\hspace{1cm}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```