# Climate flow chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, asymptote, flow-charts, calc

I am trying to draw the following "flowchart"

[image]

After some fiddling I was able to come up with the following solution

[image]

What I am struggling with mainly boils down to two things

- How can I align the arrows so that they hit the boxes at straight angles? Right now I guessed, and approximated where to put them.
- Is there an easy way to obtain fat arrows as displayed in the image?

Any alternative solutions to obtain the desired image are welcome as always.

## Code for my attempt

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{UiT-main}{HTML}{003349}
\definecolor{UiT-red}{HTML}{CB333B}
\definecolor{UiT-blue}{HTML}{007396}
\definecolor{UiT-cyan}{HTML}{59BEC9}
\definecolor{UiT-orange}{HTML}{F2A900}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,calc}

% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{sun} = [circle,minimum height=0.6cm, draw, fill=UiT-orange, 
text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{sunEmpty} = [circle,minimum height=0.6cm, 
text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=green!20, 
text width=20em, text centered, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
% Place nodes
\node [sun] (Sun) {Sun};
\node [sunEmpty,right of=Sun] (SunEmpty) {};
\node [block, right of=Sun, yshift=-2cm] (greenhouse) {Greenhouse layer};
\node [block, fill=black!20, below of=greenhouse, yshift=-2cm] (surface) {surface};
% Draw edges  
\path [line] (Sun) -- node {}($(surface.north west)!0.23!(surface.north east)$);
\path [line,shorten <=0.25cm,shorten >=0.25cm] (surface) -- node {}(greenhouse);
\path [line] ($(greenhouse.north west)!0.64!(greenhouse.north east)$) -- node {}(SunEmpty.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One way could be [Fancy arrows with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84143/13304) although is not ideal because you'll have to deal with nodes and not paths.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Such arrows have been turned into a `to path` in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/432147/121799).

Comment: @user121799: thanks for pointing it out :) Let me also briefly say I'm sad to hear you are quitting: you did impressive contributions to the community!

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Thanks for the kind words! As I said several times, I am very grateful for your nice packages. I use them*a lot* (and hope you do not mind that I occasionally "hacked" them ;-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I align the arrows so that they hit the boxes at straight
> angles? Right now I guessed, and approximated where to put them.

The coordinate `(surface.north-|sun)` will have x-coordinate value of `sun` and y-coordinate value of `surface.north`. So the `path` below will be hitting the box (`surface`) in straight angle

```
\path (Sun) -- (surface.north-|Sun);
```

> Is there an easy way to obtain fat arrows as displayed in the image?

Increase `line width`.

Also, adjusted the `outer sep` of `node`s so that arrows won't touch the nodes.
[image]

#### MWE

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{UiT-main}{HTML}{003349}
\definecolor{UiT-red}{HTML}{CB333B}
\definecolor{UiT-blue}{HTML}{007396}
\definecolor{UiT-cyan}{HTML}{59BEC9}
\definecolor{UiT-orange}{HTML}{F2A900}

% Define block styles
\tikzset{sunEmpty/.style={circle,minimum height=0.6cm, 
text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=1mm},
sun/.style={sunEmpty,draw,fill=UiT-orange},
block/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=green!20,
text width=20em, text centered, minimum height=4em, outer sep=1mm},
line/.style={-latex, line width=1.8mm, draw=blue!40}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
% Place nodes
\node [sun] (Sun) {Sun};
\node [sunEmpty,right of=Sun] (SunEmpty) {};
\node [block, right of=Sun, yshift=-2cm] (greenhouse) {Greenhouse layer};
\node [block, fill=black!20, below of=greenhouse, yshift=-2cm] (surface) {surface};
% Draw edges  
\path [line,UiT-orange] (Sun) -- (surface.north-|Sun);
\path [line] (surface) -- (greenhouse);
\path [line] (greenhouse.north-|SunEmpty) -- (SunEmpty.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### EDIT - A better version  (thanks to [user121799](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/user121799))

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm,tikz]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows,calc,shadows.blur,positioning}
\definecolor{UiT-main}{HTML}{003349}
\definecolor{UiT-red}{HTML}{CB333B}
\definecolor{UiT-blue}{HTML}{007396}
\definecolor{UiT-cyan}{HTML}{59BEC9}
\definecolor{UiT-orange}{HTML}{F2A900}

% Define block styles
\tikzset{sun/.style={circle,minimum height=0.6cm, draw, fill=UiT-orange, 
text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt, outer
sep=1mm},
sunEmpty/.style={circle,minimum height=0.6cm, 
text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt, outer
sep=1mm},
block/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=green!20, 
text width=20em, text centered, minimum height=4em, outer sep=1mm},
line/.style={-latex, double arrow, line width=1.8mm, draw=blue!40}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto,
  fat arrow/.style={% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/432147/121799
      to path={
        let \p1 = ($(\tikztotarget)-(\tikztostart)$),
            \n1 = {int(mod(scalar(atan2(\y1,\x1))+360, 360))}, % calculate angle in range [0,360)
            \n2 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)}
        in
        -- (\tikztotarget)
        node[inner xsep=0pt,inner ysep=5pt, % use inner ysep to set width
             minimum height=\n2-\pgflinewidth,
             single arrow,midway,sloped,anchor=center,
             #1          % arguments passed to fat arrow added here
             ] {} \tikztonodes}
  },
  fat arrow/.default=, % empty default for argument of fat arrow
  pft/.style={single arrow,draw=blue,blur
shadow,xshift=-2pt,minimum width=10mm, single arrow head extend=.2cm }
]
% Place nodes
\node [sun,blur shadow] (Sun) {Sun};
\node [sunEmpty,right=2.2cm of Sun] (SunEmpty) {};
\node [block, right of=Sun, yshift=-2cm,blur shadow,rounded corners=2pt] (greenhouse) {Greenhouse layer};
\node [block, fill=black!20, below of=greenhouse, yshift=-2cm,blur shadow,rounded corners=2pt] (surface) {surface};
% Draw edges  
\path [fat arrow={pft,top color=UiT-orange!80,bottom color=UiT-orange}]
(Sun.south) to (surface.north-|Sun) ;
\path [fat arrow={pft,top color=blue!20,bottom color=blue!40}]
(surface.north) to (greenhouse.south);
\path [fat arrow={pft,top color=blue!20,bottom color=blue!40,minimum width=5mm}]
(greenhouse.north-|SunEmpty) to (SunEmpty.north);
\path [fat arrow={pft,top color=blue!20,bottom color=blue!40,minimum width=5mm}]
(greenhouse.south-|SunEmpty) to (surface.north-|SunEmpty);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could use [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/432147/121799) to make the code more elegant and easy to use.