# Drawing a sphere and an ellipsoid in the same picture in TiKz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I'm working on a project an I want to put a picture like this

[image]

using Ti*k*Z but instead a fat arrow, I want to draw a curve arrow, that illustrates the fact that a function `f` sends the sphere into an ellipsoid.

Can someone help me about how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two example images named `A` and `B`. `\tikzset` give you the type of the arrow with the options of your size and position. The idea is taken from this link [Fancy arrows with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84143/fancy-arrows-with-tikz) using the best code of the user @Peter Grill that I have modificated appropriately.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\tikzset{My Arrow Style/.style={single arrow, rounded corners=1pt, fill=lightgray, anchor=center, align=center,xshift=2cm, yshift=2cm, minimum height=2cm, minimum width=2cm,text width=4cm}}
\newcommand{\MyArrow}[2][]{\tikz[baseline={([yshift=-7ex]current bounding box.center)}] \node [My Arrow Style,#1] {#2};}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
  \MyArrow{Affine trasformation}
  \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]