# How to draw a large arrow with text between two tikz pictures?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have two diagrams and I want to draw an arrow between them with a short text message in the arrow. I thought I would use [fancy arrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84147/206004). However I am not sure how to place it between the two diagrams. Here is my MWE with the arrow  line commented out.  If I uncomment it I get "TeX capacity exceeded".

```
\documentclass[standalone]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, shadows, fadings,shapes.arrows}
\tikzset{My Arrow Style/.style={single arrow, fill=red!50, anchor=base, align=center,text width=2.8cm}}
\newcommand{\MyArrow}[2][]{\tikz[baseline] \node [My Arrow Style,#1] {#2};}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black,fill=white, drop shadow,minimum size=1cm] (1) at (0, 0) {1};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black,fill=white, drop shadow,minimum size=1cm] (2) at (2, -2) {2};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black,fill=white, drop shadow,minimum size=1cm] (3) at (4, -4) {3};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black,fill=white, drop shadow,minimum size=1cm] (4) at (6, -6) {4};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black,fill=white, drop shadow,minimum size=1cm] (5) at (8, -8) {5};
    \path (1) edge [loop above] node {} (1);
    \path (2) edge [->] node {} (1);
    \path (3) edge [->] node {} (2);
    \path (4) edge [->] node {} (3);
    \path (5) edge [->] node {} (4);
    %\MyArrow[fill=yellow!50, draw=black, ultra thick, text width=3.5cm]{some text}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(13cm, -1cm)}]
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black,fill=white, drop shadow,minimum size=1cm] (1) at (0,0) {1};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black,fill=white, drop shadow,minimum size=1cm] (2) at (-2, -2) {2};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black,fill=white, drop shadow,minimum size=1cm] (3) at (0,-2) {3};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black,fill=white, drop shadow,minimum size=1cm] (4) at (2, -2) {4};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black,fill=white, drop shadow,minimum size=1cm] (5) at (4, -2) {5};

    \path (1) edge [loop above] node {} (1);
    \path (2) edge [->] node {} (1);
    \path (3) edge [->] node {} (1);
    \path (4) edge [->] node {} (1);
    \path (5) edge [->] node {} (1);
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have defined it, this arrow is a TikZ `node`. It is therefore useless to create a LaTeX command to draw it, just use the style `My Arrow Style` you have created.

To place it, with the `positioning` library, I placed it on the `right of the north anchor` of the `node (2)`

```
\node[My Arrow Style,right=of 2.north]{some text};
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[standalone]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, shadows, fadings,shapes.arrows,positioning}
\tikzset{My Arrow Style/.style={single arrow, fill=red!50, anchor=base, align=center,text width=2.8cm}}
%\newcommand{\MyArrow}[2][]{\tikz[baseline] \node [My Arrow Style,#1] {#2};}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black,fill=white, drop shadow,minimum size=1cm] (1) at (0, 0) {1};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black,fill=white, drop shadow,minimum size=1cm] (2) at (2, -2) {2};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black,fill=white, drop shadow,minimum size=1cm] (3) at (4, -4) {3};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black,fill=white, drop shadow,minimum size=1cm] (4) at (6, -6) {4};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black,fill=white, drop shadow,minimum size=1cm] (5) at (8, -8) {5};
    \path (1) edge [loop above] node {} (1);
    \path (2) edge [->] node {} (1);
    \path (3) edge [->] node {} (2);
    \path (4) edge [->] node {} (3);
    \path (5) edge [->] node {} (4);
    \node[My Arrow Style,right=of 2.north]{some text};
    \begin{scope}[shift={(13cm, -1cm)}]
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black,fill=white, drop shadow,minimum size=1cm] (1) at (0,0) {1};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black,fill=white, drop shadow,minimum size=1cm] (2) at (-2, -2) {2};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black,fill=white, drop shadow,minimum size=1cm] (3) at (0,-2) {3};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black,fill=white, drop shadow,minimum size=1cm] (4) at (2, -2) {4};
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black,fill=white, drop shadow,minimum size=1cm] (5) at (4, -2) {5};

    \path (1) edge [loop above] node {} (1);
    \path (2) edge [->] node {} (1);
    \path (3) edge [->] node {} (1);
    \path (4) edge [->] node {} (1);
    \path (5) edge [->] node {} (1);
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.