# To get an arrow white inside and black border

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-arrows, arrows, shapes

I need your support to draw an arrow like this in Tikz. White inside, black border.
I’d like to insert it between two nodes and change the length, width and head extend. Accordingly with the distance.
I got this once

`\draw[-{Triangle[width=8pt,length=5pt]}, line width=3pt] (bloco2.east) -- (bloco3.west);`

but I can’t fill it in white. I would be grateful for easy solutions.

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84143