# How to draw Sequence diagram with TeX

Tags: diagrams

I want to draw Sequence  diagram in latex. I want it to to be like the following diagram:

[image: Use case diagram]

any hint?

update [I changed the title from "use case" to "Sequence" , so sorry ]

Comment: First hint: your example is not a use case diagram: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case_diagram. Second one: https://code.google.com/p/pgf-umlsd/. Third one: questions that do not show any effort on your part, any code you tried, etc, are likely to be closed on this site.

Comment: You can read http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx for more information `:)`

Comment: Hi @rainer  , I am sorry. I just was working on my software engineering project, and I get confused between the sequence and use case diagram

Comment: I'd start by looking at [texample.net](http://www.texample.net/) to start.  Lots of examples that might get you started ... at least started enough to come back here and ask a less 'do X for me' type of question.  (I'll admit, this does not look like an easy diagram to get started with!)

Comment: @user42710 Try to use `pgf-umlsd` and if you're stuck, come back and edit your question (and add some details).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: You can find some useful tips for the general aspect of the picture in [Workflow diagram](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70320/13304).